# SVG not displaying when the sidebar is closed

Tags: css, svg

I have a sidebar that shows and hides content depending on the collapse status.

Here is a [LIVE JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/sk724gv6/65/)

Instead of using icons, I would like to use SVG images but if I use SVG images there is a jumpy effect during the transition and the SVG disappears when the sidebar is closed.

What I've tried:

```
.sidebar.close .nav-links li a .sidebarSvg{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I thought changing the opacity to 1 would do the job but I am doing something wrong.

I also tried with `display: block;` but it did not work.

Is my SVG wrong?

UPDATE:

I also tried placing the `svg` outside of the `<a>` but that makes the jumpy effect worst during the toggle transition.

Comment: please write SVG icon outside of the `<a>`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PrakashSolanki unfortunately, that is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .iocn-link {
        width:300px;
    }
```

Now You can try thsi :

```js
  let arrow = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");
  for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
    arrow[i].addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
   let arrowParent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;//selecting main parent of arrow
   arrowParent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
    });
  }
  let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  let sidebarBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-menu");
  console.log(sidebarBtn);
  sidebarBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    sidebar.classList.toggle("close");
  });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.sidebarSvg{
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 290px;
  background: #193D4C;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close{
  width: 78px;
}
.sidebar .logo-details{
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.logo-icon{
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.sidebar .logo-details i{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 78px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name{
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  margin-left:20px;
}
.sidebar.close .logo-details .logo_name{
  transition-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0 150px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links{
  overflow: visible;
}
.sidebar .nav-links::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li{
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li:hover{
  background: #193D4C;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .iocn-link{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .iocn-link{
  display: block;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li i{
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 78px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu i.arrow{
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links i.arrow{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li a{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li a .link_name{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu{
  padding: 6px 6px 14px 80px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: #193D4C;
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .sub-menu{
  display: block;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu{
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name{
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu.blank{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  padding: 3px 20px 6px 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.sidebar .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu.blank{
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.sidebar .profile-details{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 290px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #1d1b31;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details{
  background: none;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details{
  width: 78px;
}
.sidebar .profile-details .profile-content{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.sidebar .profile-details img{
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 14px 0 12px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details img{
  padding: 10px;
}
.sidebar .profile-details .profile_name,
.sidebar .profile-details .job{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sidebar.close .profile-details i,
.sidebar.close .profile-details .profile_name,
.sidebar.close .profile-details .job{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar .profile-details .job{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.home-section{
  position: relative;
  background: #E4E9F7;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 290px;
  width: calc(100% - 260px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.close ~ .home-section{
  left: 78px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
}
.home-section .home-content{
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.home-section .home-content .bx-menu,
.home-section .home-content .text{
  color: #11101d;
  font-size: 35px;
}
.home-section .home-content .bx-menu{
  margin: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.home-section .home-content .text{
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.userInitials {
    height: 38px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 38px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    color: #193D4C;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu{
    display: none;
  }
}
.dont-break {
  min-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.centered-profile {
    display:inline-block;
}

.staff-position{
    font-size: small !important;
    margin-top: 40px !important;
}

.staff-nav-holder {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.sidebar.close .nav-links li .iocn-link {
    width:300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created by CodingLab |www.youtube.com/CodingLabYT-->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Boxiocns CDN Link -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
<body>
  <div class="sidebar close">
    <div class="logo-details">
    <div class="logo-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="43.878" height="44.07" viewBox="0 0 43.878 44.07">
  <g id="g110" transform="translate(24.953 4.408)">
    <path id="path4" d="M-8.04,26.725A10.416,10.416,0,0,1-12.112,12.6,10.437,10.437,0,0,1,.23,7.767L4.939-3.049a22.3,22.3,0,0,0-28.5,13.106A22.166,22.166,0,0,0-12.748,37.54Z" fill="#f8e3a9"/>
    <path id="path6" d="M6.523-2.315,1.815,8.5A10.417,10.417,0,0,1,5.887,22.623,10.438,10.438,0,0,1-6.455,27.459l-4.708,10.815a22.3,22.3,0,0,0,28.5-13.1A22.117,22.117,0,0,0,6.523-2.315" transform="translate(0.196 0.03)" fill="#f8e3a9"/>
    <path id="path8" d="M-3.265,8.85a8.525,8.525,0,0,1,8.525,8.525A8.525,8.525,0,0,1-3.265,25.9a8.525,8.525,0,0,1-8.525-8.526h0A8.608,8.608,0,0,1-3.265,8.85" transform="translate(0.187 0.189)" fill="#f8e3a9"/>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
      <span class="logo_name dont-break">STACKOVERFLOW</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>
        <div class="iocn-link">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="userInitials">JW</span>
            <div class="col-9 staff-nav-holder">
              <span class="link_name dont-break centered-profile">John Walker</span>
              <span class="link_name staff-position">PM</span>
            </div>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow centered-profile' ></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">John Walker</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Customize your homepage</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Change your password</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="iocn-link">
          <a href="#">
            <svg class="sidebarSvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" fill="white" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><g id="icon_layer" data-name="icon layer"><path class="cls-1" d="M20.5,12H16.55a.5.5,0,0,1-.5-.5.5.5,0,0,1,.5-.5H20.5a.51.51,0,0,1,.5.5A.5.5,0,0,1,20.5,12Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M20.5,17H16.55a.5.5,0,0,1,0-1H20.5a.5.5,0,0,1,0,1Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M20.5,22H16.55a.5.5,0,0,1,0-1H20.5a.5.5,0,0,1,0,1Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M12.27,18h0a.49.49,0,0,1-.37-.18l-.8-1a.5.5,0,1,1,.76-.64l.44.52,1.44-1.58a.5.5,0,0,1,.74.67l-1.83,2A.51.51,0,0,1,12.27,18Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M22.44,5.5H21.32a.5.5,0,0,0,0,1h1.12A1.07,1.07,0,0,1,23.5,7.56V24.44a1.07,1.07,0,0,1-1.06,1.06H9.56A1.07,1.07,0,0,1,8.5,24.44V7.56A1.07,1.07,0,0,1,9.56,6.5h1.22a.5.5,0,1,0,0-1H9.56A2.06,2.06,0,0,0,7.5,7.56V24.44A2.06,2.06,0,0,0,9.56,26.5H22.44a2.06,2.06,0,0,0,2.06-2.06V7.56A2.06,2.06,0,0,0,22.44,5.5Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M12.37,7.73h7.27a.5.5,0,0,0,.5-.5V4.78a.5.5,0,0,0-.5-.5H18a2,2,0,0,0-3.88,0H12.37a.5.5,0,0,0-.5.5V7.23A.5.5,0,0,0,12.37,7.73Zm.5-2.45h1.66a.5.5,0,0,0,.5-.5,1,1,0,0,1,2,0,.5.5,0,0,0,.5.5h1.6V6.73H12.87Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M11.09,11.83l.8,1a.53.53,0,0,0,.37.18h0a.48.48,0,0,0,.37-.17l1.83-2a.5.5,0,0,0-.74-.68l-1.44,1.58-.44-.52a.5.5,0,1,0-.76.64Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M13.5,23h-2a.5.5,0,0,1-.5-.5v-2a.5.5,0,0,1,.5-.5h2a.5.5,0,0,1,.5.5v2A.5.5,0,0,1,13.5,23ZM12,22h1V21H12Z"/></g></svg>
            <span class="link_name">Projects</span>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Category</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Create a New Project</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">See All Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="iocn-link">
          <a href="#">
            <i class='bx bx-book-alt' ></i>
            <span class="link_name">Posts</span>
          </a>
          <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow' ></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a class="link_name" href="#">Posts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login Form</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Card Design</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-pie-chart-alt-2' ></i>
          <span class="link_name">Analytics</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-menu'></i>
          <span class="link_name dont-break">Collapse sidebar</span>
        </a>
      </li>

</ul>
  </div>
  <section class="home-section">
    <div class="home-content">
      
      <span class="text"></span>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question edited, I tried before but I forgot to mention it. If I write outside of the `<a>` (which makes no sense because the icons/svg must be clickable) misalignments/jumpy effects are added during the collapse transition.

Comment: now check Html and CSS code

Comment: That is promising, thanks, I upvoted. Do you have any idea of why the transition gets 'jumpy' after I toggle the sidebar?